# How to get length of std::stringstream without copying

Tags: c++

How can I get the length in bytes of a stringstream.

```
stringstream.str().length();
```

would copy the contents into std::string.  I don't want to make a copy.

Or if anyone can suggest another iostream that works in memory, can be passed off for writing to another ostream, and can get the size of it easily I'll use that.

Comment: FWIW, anyone only interested in whether a `stringstream` is empty or not may find it easier to check [`ss.peek() != decltype(ss)::traits_type::eof()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34651454/410767).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about an `ostringstream` it looks like [`tellp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp) might do what you want.

Comment: I'm using http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/
with (std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary) constructor.  tellp() works.  Thanks.

Comment: Beware that `tellp()` won't consider the initial characters. `ostringstream oss("hey"); cout << oss.tellp() << endl;` will show `0` and not `3`.

Comment: Does anyone know why `tellp()` isn't const? My `size()` method I'm writing should really be const, but clang doesn't like it. It says that `tellp` is not const. Does `tellp` modify the `stringstream`? Why should it?

Comment: Since this answer is not complete, check this link: stackoverflow.com/questions/4432793/size-of-stringstream

Answer (score 5):

A solution that provides the length of the stringstream including any initial string provided in the constructor:

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef STRINGBUFFER_H_
#define STRINGBUFFER_H_

class StringBuffer: public stringstream
{
public:
    /**
     * Create an empty stringstream
     */
    StringBuffer() : stringstream() {}

    /**
     * Create a string stream with initial contents, underlying
     * stringstream is set to append mode
     *
     * @param initial contents
     */
    StringBuffer(const char* initial)
        : stringstream(initial, ios_base::ate | ios_base::in | ios_base::out)
    {
        // Using GCC the ios_base::ate flag does not seem to have the desired effect
        // As a backup seek the output pointer to the end of buffer
        seekp(0, ios::end);
    }

    /**
     * @return the length of a str held in the underlying stringstream
     */
    long length()
    {
        /*
         * if stream is empty, tellp returns eof(-1)
         *
         * tellp can be used to obtain the number of characters inserted
         * into the stream
         */
        long length = tellp();

        if(length < 0)
            length = 0;

        return length;

    }
};
```