# How do I check if a StringStream variable is empty/null?

Tags: c++

Just a quick question here guys. I've been searching to no avail so far.

A bit more info here:

```
stringstream report_string;

report_string << "some string here...";
```

In my code itself are various conditions for assigning values to the report_string variable.

I'd like to check whether it was assigned a value or not.

Comment: Well, there are [potentially] two different "things" being asked -- what have you tried?

Comment: Define your terms. An example program where you would use this ability would help a lot (with a placeholder where you do the "check for null").

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "variable is empty/null"?  Are you saying you want to figure out if the stream contains no data?

Comment: Sorry guys. I a just added a bit more info.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`myStream.rdbuf()->in_avail()` can be used to get the count of available characters ready to be read in from a `stringstream`, you can use that to check if your `stringstream` is "empty." I'm assuming you're not actually trying to check for the value `null`.

For example if you want to extract an `int` from a `stringstream` and then see if there were any left over characters (ie. non-numeric) you could check if `myStream.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0`.

Is that something similar to what you're trying to do? I'm not sure if there's better ways but I've done this in the past and it's worked fine for me.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/in_avail

**EDIT:** I see you just updated your question as I posted.

Comment: Just what I needed. This would work fine for me since I clear the stream on every loop iteration and I'd just like to see if a value was assigned to it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Matt: rather than clearing the stream at each iteration, you could perfectly declare it within the loop and save yourself some work... and potential bugs (like using `continue` and forget about clearing it...)

Comment: I find that `rdbug()->in_avail()` always returns 0 as seems to be described in various places on the web for GNU g++.  I found Cubbi's comments at http://www.cpp.re/forum/general/233925/ informative: "it reports the size of the get area (meaning, how many bytes can be read without making a virtual call)... Without a virtual function call, there is no way for a write to touch the read-side of a stream."  My use case is simple/limited and I don't mind throwing away any characters in the stringbuffer, so I can simply test `my_stream.readsome(&test_char, 1) == 0` to confirm it is empty.

Comment: Also looking at my_stream.tellp() == 0, what about my_stream.tellg()>=mystream.tellp()?
I don't really see the get streampointer being larger than the put streampointer, but anyway. This also avoids any 0 conversion uncertainties and it is fairly clear and causes no construction.

Answer (score 17):

This method is efficient and should work with output strings as well:

```
ostringstream report_string;

if (report_string.tellp() == 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Should be `if (report_string.tellp() == std::streampos(0))`.

Comment: I like this one, of course it depends on the code not trying to do a `seekp()` on you. Also I think OP's question was about doing something if `tellp() != 0`.

Comment: @OzSolomon Could you please explain why `std::streampos(0)` is better than simply `0`? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @Yurim I don't remember now exactly why I posted that comment, but likely this is because `std::fpos` (the implementation class for `std::streampos`) has no standards-formal requirement to have a constructor that takes an int.  That means that 0 may, or may not be implicitly convertible to `streampos`, depending on your particular standard library implementation.

Comment: @OzSolomon From the "fpos requirements" in the standards we can see that `streampos` is implicitly convertible via "P p = o" where "P" is your `fpos` type (`streampos`-things) and "o" is your `streamoff` type (`int`-things). I'd always consider YAGNI before trying to guess at support for unknown compilers.

Answer (score 13):

An easy check would be to see if the string content of the stream is empty or not:

```
#include<assert.h>
#include<sstream>

int main(){
std::stringstream report_string;
report_string << ""; // an empty strin g

//emptiness check of stringstream
assert(report_string.str().empty());
}
```

Comment: The problem with the `str()` is that it potentially creates a huge block of memory just to check whether it's empty or not.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to [check the size of the internal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432793/size-of-stringstream) and compare against zero. Note that this is different from `myStream.rdbuf()->in_avail()` as AusCBlock suggests; in_avail() can return a value different from the actual size of the stream (if, for example, the internal buffer is represented with multiple non-contiguous memory blocks). In particular, `in_avail()` **can, in principle, return zero in non-empty buffers** (it's possible that the `stringbuf` specification restricts this further; I have no checked in that much detail).

Comment: This looks interesting. I might need this later on. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

Use eof() instead.

Sample Code:

```
stringstream report_string;
if ( !(report_string.eof()) ) 
    cout << "report_string EMPTY! \n";
```

Comment: From what I see, `eof()` is always false for `std::stringstream`. Haven't seen anything in the documentation. But that's how it behaves even if it's not empty.

Comment: The code in this answer is broken for the same reason `while (in.eof())` is often broken: `eof()` is only set if an earlier input attempt hit `eof()` before succeeding.  So, if say `report_string >> my_int` had read a number from the input and the last digit was the very last thing in the stream, `eof()` *would* be `true`.  But, if you used `char c = report_string.get();` to get the final character, it would succeed without trying to do anything at the end of file, and `eof()` would *not* be true.  Illustration: [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d5842d49a3c8796)

Answer (score 5):

It's normally reasonable and readable to use...

```
report_string.str().empty()
```

...but that may involve dynamic allocation and copying the entire string to a temporary, only to be thrown away.

If performance is important, another option is...

```
report_string.peek() == decltype(report_string)::traits_type::eof()
```

- this looks for a character ***not yet extracted*** from the stream, ignoring input that's already been ***successfully*** parsed/extracted

  - that's different from testing `report_string.str().empty()`, which still "sees" already-extracted input
- if earlier parsing left the stream in a `fail` state you haven't `clear()`ed, this will return `eof()` regardless of whether there are more unextracted characters

Comment: ```report_string.peek()  == std::char_traits<char>::eof()``` did the right thing for me (i.e. at least for the special case of checking whether a stringstream is unmodified) - I *think* ```std::char_traits<char>::eof()``` is probably the same as ```decltype(report_string)::traits_type::eof()```. If the check fails, I'm interested passing ```report_string.rdbuf()``` to ```std::cout``` to avoid the extra copy, so calling ```report_string.str()``` would have made that optimization pointless. (calling ```rdbuf``` without the check has side effects, and may throw).

Comment: @Apriori: `std::char_traits<char>::eof()` will be the same if `report_string` is instantiated for `char` - yours is simpler, but an extra point of maintenance if `report_string`'s type changes one day - much of a muchness all up.  Interesting insight about `rdbuf()` potentially throwing - I didn't think that could happen!  Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is very old and already answered, but depending on the situation there might also be yet another approach worth considering:

When you are testing if a stringstream is empty, you properly intend to do something with either the individual strings or each line in the stringstream; thus you will most likely be using either the `>>` operator or `std::getline` on the stringstream... and if the stream is empty these simply have the value false, thus you could write:

```
stringstream report_string;

foo(report_string)// some functions which may or may not write to report_string

string single_report;//string to read to

bool empty=true;//First assume it was empty
while(getline(report_string,single_report))//Alternatively use report_string>>single_report if you don't want entire lines
{
    empty=false;//...it wasn't empty
    bar(single_report);//Do whatever you want to do with each individual appended line 
}

if (empty)
{
    //... whatever you want to do if the stream was empty goes here
}
```

It should be noted that this approach assumes that you were planning on cycling through the stringstream; if you were not, then this approach can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

How about another approach?

If you make the ostringstream an optional type you can check that its been assigned to before using it.

Imagine a class called `lazy<>` which lazily constructs an object when needed, then we could do this:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto oss1 = lazy<std::ostringstream>();
    auto oss2 = lazy<std::ostringstream>();

    use(oss1) << "Hello";

    if (oss1) cout << use(oss1).str() << endl;
    if (oss2) cout << use(oss2).str() << endl;

    if_used(oss1, [](auto& ss) { cout << ss.str() << endl; });
    if_used(oss2,
            [](auto& ss) { cout << ss.str() << endl; },
            [](auto& oss) { cout << "oss2 is not used" << endl; });

    use(oss2) << "Goodbye";
    if_used(oss2, [](auto& ss) { cout << ss.str() << endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

yielding this output:

```
Hello
Hello
oss2 is not used
Goodbye
```

Advantages:

- no redundant construction of the `stringstream` when not used.
- optional provides an exception if the unused stringstream is subsequently used (via const reference)

Full example below with customisable constructor:

I've used `std::experimental` for the `optional`, but you could just as easily use `boost::optional`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sstream>

using std::experimental::optional;

namespace detail {
    template<class T, class Constructor>
    struct lazy final
    {
        template<class Con , std::enable_if_t< not std::is_same<std::decay_t<Con>, lazy>::value > * = nullptr>
        lazy(Con&& con)
        : _constructor(std::forward<Con>(con))
        {}

        T& get() {
            if (not bool(_opt)) {
                _opt = _constructor();
            }
            return *_opt;
        }

        const T& get() const {
            return *_opt;
        }

        bool used() const {
            return bool(_opt);
        }

        operator bool() const {
            return used();
        }

    private:
        Constructor _constructor;
        optional<T> _opt;
    };

    template<class T>
    struct default_construct {
        T operator()() const { return T(); }
    };

    struct no_action {
        template<class T>
        void operator()(T&) const { }
    };
}


template<class T, class Constructor = detail::default_construct<T> >
auto lazy(Constructor&& con = detail::default_construct<T>())
{
    return detail::lazy<T, std::decay_t<Constructor>>(std::forward<Constructor>(con));
}

template<class T, class Constructor>
auto& use(detail::lazy<T, Constructor>& l)
{
    return l.get();
}

template<class T, class Constructor>
auto& use(const detail::lazy<T, Constructor>& l)
{
    return l.get();
}

template<class T, class Constructor, class F, class Else = detail::no_action>
void if_used(detail::lazy<T, Constructor>& l, F&& f, Else&& e = detail::no_action())
{
    if (l.used())
        f(l.get());
    else
        e(l);
}

template<class T, class Constructor, class F, class Else = detail::no_action>
void if_used(const detail::lazy<T, Constructor>& l, F&& f, Else&& e)
{
    if (l.used())
        f(l.get());
    else
        e(l);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto oss1 = lazy<std::ostringstream>();
    auto oss2 = lazy<std::ostringstream>();

    use(oss1) << "Hello";

    if (oss1) cout << use(oss1).str() << endl;
    if (oss2) cout << use(oss2).str() << endl;

    if_used(oss1, [](auto& ss) { cout << ss.str() << endl; });
    if_used(oss2,
            [](auto& ss) { cout << ss.str() << endl; },
            [](auto& oss) { cout << "oss2 is not used" << endl; });

    use(oss2) << "Goodbye";
    if_used(oss2, [](auto& ss) { cout << ss.str() << endl; });

    return 0;
}
```