# invalid numbers always fall to 0?

Tags: c++, cin

```
cout << "Enter a positive integer or zero: ";
getline(cin, streamStr);
stringstream(streamStr) >> number;
if (!number) {
    cout << "invalid input detected or the input is too big.\n";
    return 1;
}
```

inputs like "%234" or "sdf2334" always fall to 0 , which is false in bool expression, but 0 is still a number.
How to check if the input is really invalid like "%234"??

Comment: `number` isn't being set to anything. It retains its previous value here. You should be checking the result of the reading, not the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the returned value of the `operator>>`, which is not the same as the value of the variable you're reading into:

```
if (stringstream(streamStr) >> number) {
    ...
```

So what's the returned value, then? If you check the docs, you'll see it's a stream itself. It goes to the `operator bool` of it (because it's used in an `if` statement), which in turn returns the validity of the stream, or, IOW, if the last operation succeeded.

If you want to ensure the stream doesn't contain anything besides the number use

```
if (sstream.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0) { 
    // something is still there
```

And to skip whitespace at the end if you want to allow it:

```
sstream >> std::ws;
```

---

So, all in all...

```
template<typename T, 
    // those are optional
    enable_if<is_default_constructible<T>::value>::type,
    enable_if<is_input_streamable<T>::value>::type
>
optional<T> myRead(string input, bool allowTrailingWs = true) {
    stringstream str(input);
    T val;

    // check parsing
    if (!(str >> val))
        return none;

    // allow whitespace at the end
    if (allowTrailingWs)
        str >> std::ws;

    // check if there's any garbage left
    if (str.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0)
        return none;

    return val;
}
```

The code above is *just for illustration purposes*. Shall you need more advanced parsing, check out Boost.Spirit.

---

Also, [apparently this isn't guaranteed to work every time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8046472/752976). Using:

```
    auto inputEnd = ss.tellg();
    ss.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    if (inputEnd == ss.tellg()) {
```

To check if the `ss` is empty could help fix that.

Comment: I just tried. If I entered "2342fdsf", the conversion is eligible, why it does not fall into the false state?? because when it tries to convert "f" into number,it should fail. My code is --> if (!(stringstream(streamStr) >> firstOperand[count]))....

Comment: @Joshua [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9ecba1e81e1cfa1) (and a use example, actually)

Comment: @Joshua: `if (somestream >> number)` checks that - after any whitespace is optionally skipped - there's at least one digit.  The conversion stops - have been deemed a success - after any legal characters (e.g. if reading a float, `0`, `E` etc. are legal parts of the potential representation).  So, if you want to check there's nothing else in the stream, you can use `char c; if (the_stream >> my_var && !(the_stream >> c))` to ensure no further non-whitespace characters can be parsed after the character.

Comment: @TonyD I've got another method, added that after I've realized the OP might want that. Your solution looks ok, too.

Comment: @Joshua I've added a part that might interest you.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: oh good - that doesn't ignore trailing whitespace, but can be enough for some streams/protocols....  Cheers!

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Christmas comes early - hurray! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you understand how streams work. Allow me to address your misconception:

The stream won't attempt to extract any value into `number` if the data being evaluated doesn't correspond to formatting requirements of the type. Extraction works by the stream iterating through each character in the character sequence one by one, and testing each character as a viable datum for the type to which the extraction is targeted. If the character is not viable, extraction stops (this is why you are seeing success upon entering something like `"2342fdsf"`; the stream will keep extracting until it finds an invalid character. `"2342"` are valid characters for an integer while `"f"` is not)

If the stream finds an invalid character, nothing further is done to the variable (in this case `number`). In fact, it is implementation-defined what value an uninitialized variable has if extraction failed to produce any characters. With that in mind, it is potentially dangerous to check the value of the operand to determine if I/O failed. This is where checking the stream state comes in:

> ```
> std::istringstream iss(streamStr);
>
> if (iss >> number)
> {
>     std::cout << "Extraction produced: " << number << '\n';
> }
> ```

If the extractions fails, the stream will set the appropriate bits. The stream will then be implicitly converted to a boolean using `operator bool()` (or `operator void*()` pre-C++11 where it will subsequently undergo conversion to boolean). The boolean function will check the stream state using `!this->fail()` (which checks both `badbit` and `failbit`) and if the function returns true, the `if` body will be executed.

If the stream is *not* in a good state (`!this->fail()` returns false), that means the extraction failed to produce a value and the `if` statement body goes unevaluated.

Answer (score 1):

By encasing the *extraction* in a conditional check, not the value of the thing you tried to extract into.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `number` must be a char value, try using the cctype library which is helpful for dealing with strings. It has functions such as

```
isdigit(Char_Exp) //Returns true if the value is a digit
```

and

```
isctrl(Char_Exp) //Returns true if the value is a control character like %(modulus)
```

Here is a link to a C++ cctype library reference:  [cctype library reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/)

To test `number` I would advise you create a function of type Boolean and so that it tests all possible input errors at once.

Comment: *To test number I would advise you create a function of type Boolean and so that it tests all possible input errors at once.* - can you elaborate on that? Other than that, "try using standard library" doesn't really help here. Perhaps you could write a bit more on how those functions should be used in this case.

Comment: The stream already contains functionality to determine if the extraction produced an acceptable value. That being said, it is very much unnecessary to use these functions - at all.