# c++ How to check if ostringstream is empty

Tags: c++, std

I want to check if ostringstream object is empty i.e. it does not hold any character sequence?

I checked [cpp reference for ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/) but it was still not clear to me.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message actually? You'll need `if(oss.str().empty())` probably? Even that crappy reference you're referring to tells you that there's no such function.

Comment: You could use the `str()` method to retrieve the contents and check if its empty, or you could use its [`peek()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) method

Comment: using str() creates a copy of the contents in the buffer which is not great for my usecase http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/str/

Comment: @amey91 _"using str() creates a copy of the contents in the buffer"_ It [doesn't](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream/str) your reference is probably wrong about that, or you misunderstood it. I said that reference you are using is merely useless s**t.

Comment: Since you linked the docs that show that `empty` isn't a method on stringstream, I removed the part about using a known-not-present method resulting in a syntax error.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you're confusing [std::ostrstream::str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream/str) with [std::basic_ostringstream::str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str)?  ostringstream is [defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) as basic_ostringstream<char>

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are referencing deprecated `ostrstream`, while @amey91 references `ostringstream`.

Comment: @Paul [I see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str), sorry.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ:  ostringstream::str() returns a **copy** of the contents, so it is the least efficient way to do it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046357/how-do-i-check-if-a-stringstream-variable-is-empty-null/8046449

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check its size the way you would for any other `std::ostream` subclass:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
std::streampos pos = ofs.tellp();  // store current location
ofs.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);  // go to end
bool empty = (ofs.tellp() == 0);   // check size == 0 ?
ofs.seekp(pos);                    // restore location
```

For an input stream (`istringstream`, `ifstream`, etc), then you'd use `tellg()` and `seekg()` instead.

Q: Do you need to flush the stream before getting its size?

A: In theory, you don't, but the std documentation does not mention anything about it... So the need to do so probably depends on the implementation.

On an `std::ostream`, I'd recommend it, if you've inserted bytes recently, and are not located already at the end of the stream.  In most use cases involving output stream you will be appending to the stream and be located at its far end, it is not necessary in this case to store and restore the seek pointer location.

Flushing an `std::ostringstream` is not an expensive operation, in any case. On an output file stream, I'd personally call `flush()`, since I would not get the size of the stream in the middle of an operation anyway.

To sum it up, my personal advice is to flush output streams before getting their size, unless you know for sure you are at the end.

Note that for `std::ifstream`, the technique above is the only way to get the size of the file.

Comment: Do you need to flush the stream before measuring?  If not, why not?